# Only synchronising certain files

Tags: ubuntu-one

I would like to sync my eclipse workspace on ubuntu one, but this could become very big, with a lot of unnessecary files, how could I get ubuntu one to only sync *.java files in a folder structure?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use git and only add the `.java` files to the git repo.  Then have a folder in your U1 shared folder as a remote?

Seems like a really simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Ubuntu One supports ignoring certain files, but not syncing *only* specific files. The previous git suggestion sounds reasonable.